# CSS change div background image whisch is in a folder

Tags: html, css

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title>Title</title>

<style>

  .parallax
   {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url(Pictures/BackUS.png);


    height: 100%;


    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

  <div class="parallax"></div>
```

[image: Picture]

`"aa"` is the page which the code is in, the picture is the folder `"Pictuers"` and it's named `BackUS.png`. All of it in folder `"User"`.

How to write this line:

```
 background-image: url(Pictures/BackUS.png);
```

Comment: You already wrote it, what is the problem?

Comment: @gevorg it's now working, all I see is blank page.

Comment: Which folder is the CSS in, bearing in mind that the URL (in the CSS) is relative to the CSS stylesheet, not the page in which it's used. Have you looked at the 'resources' (or similar) tab of your web developer tools (F12 in most browsers) to see whether the image is loading/found at all?

Comment: @DavidThomas The css is also in `User`. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">`. But I wrote it on the page itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Pictures Folder is in the same folder as the html code this should work. Please be aware the **div must have a size** to see the picture in the back. (You should adapt the size to the picture pixels.)

```
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .parallax {
                /* The image used */
                    background-image: url(Pictures/BackUS.png);


                    height: 100%;


                    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
                    background-attachment: fixed;
                    background-position: center;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
  <div class="parallax" >Hello</div>
</body>
```

Comment: As I think the problem was your DIV has no size so you dont see the picture, as I changed the size (added the Hello) I saw the background picture.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the quotes around the path.

`background-image: url("Pictures/BackUS.png");`

Comment: Quotes are optional here, and only required if the URL contains white-space, or other 'special' characters.

Comment: Are you opening this page in a browser? Does the log there show any errors?

Comment: @YashCapoor No errors, I even put another div with a different class and it is working on the other class...

Comment: Do you have any other CSS files linked in aa.aspx that could contain definitions overwriting the definition for the 'parallax' class?

Comment: @YashCapoor It's working now, it was because the div had no size. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
background-image: url(../Pictures/BackUS.png);
```